# Mean Well power source doesn't start on battery

Tags: power-supply

I power an amplifier using ADD-55 power source with "built in UPS functionality".
As supposed, it charges a battery connected to "battery" output, and continues to run on it when mains power fails.

What I don't understand is why power source doesn't *start* on that battery. I.e. I have a spare charged battery "in the field", no mains power, and I want to switch on the amplifier.
Unexpectedly, the only way to start without mains power is to connect a battery to +V output of power source (not "battery" output).

What is proper way to arrange such a cold start?

Addition: power source is ADD-55A, load is custom built RF amplifier, battery is lead-acid 12V 3A*h, circuit is trivial:

[image: add-55a battery backup]

Comment: Please explain in detail or draw a diagram how exactly you have connected the batteries and loads to the power supply. Also add what is the exact power supply model (ADD-55 is not exact enough), what is the load, and what kind of battery you are using.

Comment: Ask Meanwell if what you're trying to do is supported. After a quick skim of the datasheet I don't see anything indicating that it should work, but they could confirm.

Comment: How much current your amplifier takes?

Comment: I would like to know general answer (kind a review) about cold start of such sources, to use them in another, different projects too.